# retrieve file from FTP when the directory has too many files

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons

Iam trying to get a list of FTP files by using

```
FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles(READ_DIRECTORY);
```

There are more than 27553 files in this directory and i expect the number to grow. 
Now i need to retrieve one file from this huge list. I am doing the following

```
 for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles)
       {
        if(fileName.equalsIgnoreCase(ftpFile.getName())
          {
           print(ftpFile);
          }
       }
```

But lets say the file i want to print is the last file in the 27553 files.. it takes about a minute to go through the whole list checking if its the file im looking for.. not only that.. it also gives me a "org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection." after about 900 seconds.

How can i tune this program to find the file faster? I dont want it to run for 900 seconds. Below is the actual method that takes so long. Please suggest how i can reduce the time taken. In debug mode, the method runs hundreds of seconds. On a production server, it takes more than a minute or two which is still not acceptable.

```
private boolean PDFReport(ActionForm form, HttpServletResponse response,
        String fileName, String READ_DIRECTORY) throws Exception
{
    boolean test = false;
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    DataSourceReader dsr = new DataSourceReader();
    dsr.getFtpLinks();
    String ftppassword = dsr.getFtppassword();
    String ftpserver = dsr.getFtpserver();
    String ftpusername = dsr.getFtpusername();
    ftp.connect(ftpserver);
    ftp.login(ftpusername, ftppassword);
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try
    {
        int reply;
        reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply))
        {
            ftp.disconnect();
            System.out.println("FTP server refused connection.");
        } else
        {
            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftp.listFiles(READ_DIRECTORY);
            for (FTPFile ftpFile : ftpFiles)
            {
                    String FilePdf = ftpFile.getName();
                    ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
                    if (FilePdf.equalsIgnoreCase(fileName))
                    {
                        String strFile = READ_DIRECTORY + "/" + FilePdf;
                        boolean fileFormatType = fileName.endsWith(".PDF");
                        if (fileFormatType)
                        {
                            if (FilePdf != null && FilePdf.length() > 0)
                            {
                                is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(strFile);
                                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                                response.reset();
                                response.setContentType("application/pdf");
                                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                        "inline;filename=example.pdf");
                                ServletOutputStream outputStream = response
                                        .getOutputStream();

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int readCount;

                                while ((readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                                {
                                    outputStream
                                            .write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                                }
                                outputStream.flush();
                                outputStream.close();
                            }
                        } else
                        {
                            if (FilePdf != null && FilePdf.length() > 0)
                            {
                                is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(strFile);
                                bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
                                response.reset();
                                response.setContentType("application/TIFF");
                                response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                                        "inline;filename=example.tiff");
                                ServletOutputStream outputStream = response
                                        .getOutputStream();

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int readCount;

                                while ((readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0)
                                {
                                    outputStream
                                            .write(buffer, 0, readCount);
                                }
                                outputStream.flush();
                                outputStream.close();
                            }
                        }
                        test = true;
                    }
                    if(test) break;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Exception ----->" + ex.getMessage());

    } finally
    {

        try
        {
            if (bis != null)
            {
                bis.close();
            }
            if (is != null)
            {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try
        {

            ftp.disconnect();
            ftp = null;

        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    return test;
}
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. It doesn't take a minute to search an array for one item, and a minute is a lot less than 900 seconds. Are you doing this repetitively?.  If so, try loading them into a Map first, keyed on getName().

Comment: I am using eclipse in Debug mode. No repetetions. Thats how i wrote the loop

Comment: Well you haven't answered the question about the 900 seconds, and your loop doesn't break after you find the file, and you may be including printing time as well as the time to get to the end of the array whether you found the file or not, ...

Comment: im gonna post the actual program now.. gimme a few secs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother iterating through the full list?  You already know what the filename you want is, and you use it when you call `is = ftp.retrieveFileStream(strFile);`.  Just call that directly without ever calling `listFiles()`.

Comment: The two places where you do (nearly) the same thing for PDFs as for TIFFs is also begging for a helper method...

Answer (score 0):

I think it has 2 ways depend on how you gonna used it.

1. instead of using "listFiles" get a list of file name and info, you use "listName" to get only files' name.

   String[] ftpFiles = ftp.listName(READ_DIRECTORY);
     // do looping for string array
2. using FTPFileFilter with listFiles

   ```
   FTPFileFilter filter = new FTPFileFilter() {

      @Override
      public boolean accept(FTPFile ftpFile) {

         return (ftpFile.isFile() && 
            ftpFile.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(fileName);
      }
   };

   FTPFile[] ftpFiles= ftp.listFiles(READ_DIRECTORY, filter);

   if (ftpFiles!= null && ftpFiles.length > 0) {

      for (FTPFile aFile : ftpFiles) {
         print(aFile.getName());
      }
   }
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use a for-each loop. Use a regular for loop where you can actually control the direction.

```
for(int i = ftpFiles.Length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    print(ftpFiles[i])
}
```

Comment: how will this for loop improve the performance? it still goes thru 27553 filenames.

Comment: I might have interpreted your question a little too literal. You did say "But lets say the file i want to print is the last file in the 27553 files"